# Array length from ELF file

Tags: elf

I have an `ELF` file and I can extract symbol and section information using `readelf` just fine.
I run into a problem because I need to know which variables are arrays and what length they have. I only get the raw size. I found someone saying that you might find this information using `--debug-dump` in the debug section (which definitely does contain a lot of information, but I can't find the array sizes I'm looking for).

I have a modified GCC for an embedded target if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of debugging information does your target use?  If it is DWARF, an array variable will have an associated type with tag `DW_TAG_array_type`, and that should have a `DW_AT_upper_bound` attribute, which is one less than the array size (for C arrays).

Alternatively, if your kind of debugging information only provides the array element type, you could use the ELF object size and divide it by the size of the array elements.

Comment: Is there by chance a .NET library that parses this information?

Comment: It doesn't look this way, which isn't too surprising because Windows uses PE/COFF. I looked at [Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono), and it uses C code for dealing with ELF files.